# How to get the currently loaded configuration in a Symfony application?

Tags: configuration, symfony

I changed the config (`config.yml`) and want to check, if it worked.

**How can I see the actually loaded configurations?** Can I access them from a `Controller`?

Comment: There is no master config object representing the currently loaded configuration.  Symfony "compiles" the config into a bunch of different objects.  It is quite powerful and well worth understanding: http://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#learn-more But there is nothing like what I assume you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Sure, Symfony merges all configs and process them. But the result is one big nested object or array. In Zend Framework I can: 1. see all the loaded configs in the Zend Developer Tools bar and 2. get all the actually loaded configs from the `Config` service. So I expected a similar functionality in Symfony: 1. in the Web Debug Toolbar and 2. somewhere in the (`Controller`) code.

Comment: Alas, in this case your expectations will result in disappointment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your app first time starts, Sf uses a HttpKernel component to manage the loading of the service container configuration from the application and bundles and also handles the compilation and caching.

After the compilation process has loaded the services from the configuration, extensions and the compiler passes, it is dumped so that the cache can be used next time. The dumped version is then used during subsequent requests as it is more efficient.

More info at: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/workflow.html

If you dump $this->container in your controller, you will see all the parameters inside private property parameters, including parameters defined in the parameters.yml file and in the config.yml

[image]

Let's say that you want to know what is current value of the parameter locale - you can write this

```
$this->container->getParameter('locale')
```

Also, all those parameters are dumped into sf_root/var/cache/your_env/appDevDebugProjectContainer.xml

Comment: I tried it out, but some configs are not there. E.g.: I defined `twig    cache: false` in my `/app/config/config_dev.yml` (the file is loaded). But the `container` (`var_dump($this->container)` in a `Controller`) doesn't "know" anything about this setting.

Comment: Sorry, now I found it, as `originalCache`. Thank you for your help!

Comment: No problem. Also, you can var_dump  $this->container->get('twig') to get more info about twig environment